# CAN bus protocol to command/control fuel pump relay off

Tags: can-bus, scan-tool

I am trying to capture the CAN bus frame responsible for turning off the fuel pump relay.  I have an OEM scanner which commands the fuel pump relay off, and I capture all CAN frames during that time.  I then replay all frames but the fuel pump relay will not turn off.

I'm familiar with ECU's broadcasting sensor/device information using unique arbitration ID's, but that's a one-way (broadcast ) process.  What about commanding an ECU - is there handshaking involved?

Does anyone have information on this handshaking?  (This is NOT the same as OBD2 flow control).  Or why does the replay not work?

Comment: I've seen you've asked scan-tool questions in the past, but then after a while you delete them when you haven't gotten an answer. I don't know if you've found the answer or given up the search. I would ask if you've found the answer, please do not delete the original question, but rather post up what you've found as an answer to yourself. This is not only a help to yourself, but to the whole community.

Comment: As I learn more I realize one of my questions might not make sense (which is why I suspect no one answered), so I deleted it.

Comment: I think the reason nobody is answering these types of questions is because the knowledge base just isn't here. I'm not trying to say the questions are off topic, as they directly relate to the site, it's just we don't have anyone here who has the knowledge. If, after you figure something out, you have to modify the question somewhat for it to make sense, then put the answer to the question behind it, I think it would go a long way to bringing that knowledge here to the site. I know I would sure love to learn more in this area.

Comment: When I leave unanswered questions on SE forums eventually someone comes down votes it (with no explanation), and my reputation sinks.  so I don't leave unanswered questions.  I wish SE would disallow that behavior.  You must comment if you want to downvote.

Comment: Well, since voting in general isn't a thing or an issue here on MVM&R, you won't have that problem.

Comment: GM EFI; ecm commands fuel pump operation 2-3 seconds when ignition switch is turned on, engine not started. I presume this is for safety. Why run the pump if the engine isn't started? When starting, the ecm turns pump on due to timing signals from the crank sensor as the crankshaft rotates. The ecm cannot run the EFI system if the crank sensor fails to send precise timing signals because it is the electronic heartbeat of the ecm.  If you accept this and apply it to whatever vehicle you're studying, you may be able to decode canbus signaling between engine sensors and ecm.